# Replace package from one repo with the same package from another repo

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg, debian-stretch

On my debian box, some time ago I needed a newer version of PHP than was available through official repo. I installed these from `dotdeb` repo (i.e. all php packages have `-dotdeb-` as part of the version. This worked fine, however now that the version is available from the official repo, I want to start using that one. There are about 20 packages from that repo.

What's the easiest way to replace installed packages with packages with the same package names but from different repo? Note that the original repo has been removed from `sources.list.d` and is no longer available.

Comment: Are you going from PHP5 to PHP7? If so this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04) might be of use.

Comment: @Burgi no, I already have PHP 7, but it was installed from unofficial repo. I want to replace them with the official ones.

Answer (score 0):

An untested try by a non-Linux user:

```
yum list installed | grep @OLD-REPO | awk '{print $1}' >packagelist
yum reinstall `cat packagelist`
```

Comment: Yum is for redhat based systems. I am on Debian.

Comment: You can swap `yum` for `apt-get` or `apt`